# Форматирование элементов массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
  let min = 1 // минимальное значение
  let max = 100 // максимальное значение
  const num = []
  for (min; min<max+1; min++) { // генератор чисел
      num.push(min) // запись результата в массив
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('.fff p').innerHTML = num
```

Этот код выводит длинную строчку, которая не помещается на экране и появляется полоса прокрутки. С помощью CSS на нее воздействовать не получается.

Хотелось бы, примерно так:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
11,12,13,14,15,16,17...
```

Как можно отформатировать элементы массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... = num.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте эти свойства к элементу с текстом, который нужно обрезать точкам. Ширину дополнительно вручную задайте через `width`, если так не работает.

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```